# react-infinite-scroll-component load more with array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to do an infinite scroll with my data that is an array. Most examples I see uses an API call and it got `pages` included on it but I'm having trouble doing it with just an array and values to set how many objects to load per scroll. Here's my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component'

const Scroll = ({ tweets }) => {
  const [allTweets, setAllTweets] = useState(tweets)
  const [hasMore, setHasmore] = useState(true)
  const [lastPosition, setLastPosition] = useState(0)
  const perPage = 4

  const loadProducts = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAllTweets(...allTweets, tweets.slice(lastPosition, lastPosition + perPage))
    }, 4000)

    setLastPosition(lastPosition + perPage)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProducts()
  }, [allTweets])

  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={allTweets.length}
      next={loadProducts}
      hasMore={hasMore}
      endMessage={
        <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
        </p>
      }
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        {allTweets &&
          allTweets.slice(lastPosition, lastPosition + perPage).map((value, index) => {
            return <div className="py-10 px-5">{value.body}</div>
          })}
      </div>
    </InfiniteScroll>
  )
}

export default Scroll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [semi-functioning example](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-wood-23ukf?file=/src/App.js) of what I think you are trying to do.  Note that this plugin only seems to work *if you can scroll*.  If your content is not tall enough to force scrolling then new content will never be able to load:

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Scroll from "./Scroll";

const App = () => {
  const initialTweets = [
    { body: "Body 1" },
    { body: "Body 2" },
    { body: "Body 3" },
    { body: "Body 4" },
    { body: "Body 5" },
    { body: "Body 6" },
    { body: "Body 7" },
    { body: "Body 8" },
    { body: "Body 9" },
    { body: "Body 10" }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>demo: react-infinite-scroll-component</h1>
      <hr />
      <Scroll tweets={initialTweets} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Scroll.jsx

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const Scroll = ({ tweets }) => {
  const [allTweets, setAllTweets] = useState(tweets);
  const [hasMore, setHasmore] = useState(true);
  const [lastPosition, setLastPosition] = useState(0);
  const perPage = 4;

  const loadProducts = useCallback(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAllTweets((prev) => [...prev, ...prev]);
    }, 2000);

    setLastPosition(lastPosition + perPage);
  }, []);

  console.log(allTweets);

  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={allTweets.length}
      next={loadProducts}
      hasMore={hasMore}
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        {allTweets.map((value, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="py-10 px-5">
            {value.body}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
};

export default Scroll;
```

You'll need to tweak things to do exactly what you want, but this should point you in the right direction.

NOTE: To see this work in the codesandbox, either shrink the demo window so you can scroll or add a log more objects to the `initialTweets` array.  Also, there are a number of examples you can find on the [project's homepage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component#live-examples).

Comment: Thank you for the idea!! I was able to make it work with this

`const perPage = 11;
  const [lastPosition, setLastPosition] = useState(perPage);
  const [allTweets, setAllTweets] = useState(tweets.slice(0, perPage));
  const [hasMore, setHasmore] = useState(true);

  const loadProducts = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAllTweets((prev) => [...prev, ...tweets.slice(lastPosition, lastPosition + perPage)]);
    }, 4000);

    setLastPosition(lastPosition + perPage);
  };`